# Rxjava : Maybe flatmap with completable

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm using an external API with two functions, one that returns a `Maybe` and one that returns a `Completable` (see code below). I'd like my function 'saveUser()' to return a **Completable**, so that I can just check it with `doOnSuccess()` and `doOnError`. But currently my code doesn't compile. Also please note that if my 'getMaybe' doesn't return anything, I'd like to get a null value as an argument in my flatmap, so that I can handle the null vs not-null cases (as seen in the code).

```
    private Maybe<DataSnapshot> getMaybe(String key) {
        // external API that returns a maybe
    }

    private Completable updateChildren(mDatabase, childUpdates) {
        // external API that returns a Completable
    }

    // I'd like my function to return a Completable but it doesn't compile now
    public Completable saveUser(String userKey, User user) {
        return get(userKey)
                .flatMap(a -> {
                    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();

                    if (a != null) {
                        // add some key/values to childUpdates
                    }

                    childUpdates.put(DB_USERS + "/" + userKey, user.toMap());

                    // this returns a Completable
                    return updateChildren(mDatabase, childUpdates)
                });
    }
```

Comment: Can you put the compiler errors in the question?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, remember that Maybe is use to get one element, empty or an error
I refactor your code below to make posible return a Completable

```
public Completable saveUser(String userKey, User user) {
    return getMaybe(userKey)
            .defaultEmpty(new DataSnapshot)
            .flatMapCompletable(data -> {
                Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();

                //Thanks to defaultempty the object has an 
                //Id is null (it can be any attribute that works for you) 
                //so we can use it to validate if the maybe method
                //returned empty or not
                if (data.getId() == null) {
                    // set values to the data
                    // perhaps like this
                    data.setId(userKey);
                    // and do whatever you what with childUpdates
                }

                childUpdates.put(DB_USERS + "/" + userKey, user.toMap());

                // this returns a Completable
                return updateChildren(mDatabase, childUpdates);
            });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I finally came up with.

```
    public Completable saveUser(String userKey, User user) {
        return getMaybe(userKey)
                .map(tripListSnapshot -> {
                    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
                    // // add some key/values to childUpdates
                    return childUpdates;
                })
                .defaultIfEmpty(new HashMap<>())
                .flatMapCompletable(childUpdates -> {
                    childUpdates.put(DB_USERS + "/" + userKey, user.toMap());
                    return updateChildren(mDatabase, childUpdates);
                });
    }
```

Comment: Actually defaultIfEmpty is checking if the ´map´ returned ´childUpdates´ it is not checking if `getMaybe()` got an empty value